# Where is the IP Address is a TCP header - How does Layer 3 know were aplication is sending the packet

Tags: tcp, ip, encapsulation

The TCP header includes the port information - understood.
But as the packet/segment is sent down to Layer 3 to encapsulate it as an IP packet, how does layer 3 know what destination IP address to use - which is specified in the application layer. There is no where in the TCP header to inform L3 of the destination IP address. Is there a backchannel for this information ? If so what is the backchannel ?

Comment: Well, how does the TCP layer know the port number? It's the same question. NB TCP does not use [tag:osi] in any way.

Comment: So I have been taught this maybe 6 times and every time, it is taught the layer above hands the information it has "directly down" to the layer below for  further encapsulation. This would imply that everything needed was somehow included.  Another user commented that the application makes a call to the OS  which somehow shepards the information through the TCP > Networking layers which makes some sense. That would be the back channel.   Thanks for your answer wrt to OSI !

Answer (score 0):

> how does layer 3 know what destination IP address to use - which is specified in the application layer.

Information are not somehow forwarded from the application layer to the network layer. If an application creates a TCP socket and then calls `connect` on it it gives both the IP address and the port to the OS. The OS then will use these information to encapsulate the data for the connection in an IP packet.

Comment: Thank you so much for this missing piece!